# Android - Unable to Display Actions in Notification bar

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am developing the Actionable Notifications in Android.

```
void createActionableNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
            .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.moneybag)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.moneybag, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.moneybag, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.moneybag, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // hide the notification after its selected

    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

So it displays Actions Like this , Please check the Image below.
[image]

The app is runnning with the target SDK, Compile SDK API is 24, Min SDK is 20. 
I tested with Marshmallow Device. But In emulator It works fine . Emulator SDK version is 24
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this: works for api >= 16

```
 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(myContext)
.setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
            .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.moneybag)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .addAction(R.drawable.moneybag, "Call", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.moneybag, "More", pIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.moneybag, "And more", pIntent).build();

//The rest of your options
.build();
```

The buttons won't appear when there is any Ongoing `Notification` present in the list, such as a media player control, or you have phone connected to PC via USB or when you are editing text...

you can try `Notification.PRIORITY_MAX` to get around this, or `PRIORITY_HIGH`

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I tried Priority and setwhen(0) too. But no change. I dont have any ongoing notifications in my phone @rafsanahmad007

Comment: try adding style in your notification:`.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(th_alert))`

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720670/implement-expand-and-collapse-notification-android

Comment: also try unplugging the USB

Comment: in extension to this statement -> `The buttons won't appear when there is any Ongoing Notification present in the list, such as a media player control, or you have phone connected to PC via USB or when you are editing text...`  also make sure that `u are not downloading anything as well`