# Is it possible to send Firebase(FCM) notification message(multiple lined message) in the push notification with expandable option on it; using Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I searched for the solution but could not find any relevant results.

This is what i am trying but didn't get desired output -

```
message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
notification=messaging.Notification(
title="Title",
body="body line1\nbody line2\nbody line3\nbody line4\nbody line5\nbody line6"),
tokens=['eg-token1','eg-token2','eg-token3',...,'eg-tokenN']
 )
messaging.send_multicast(message)
```

Ok! Straight forward,
In below attached image you can see `green` squared expand option for `WhatsApp` and `Gmail chat` notification. I want the same for my `red` squared notification that i sent using firebase FCM.

If it's not possible using FCM then how we can achieve this!?

[image]**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on how the notification is being handled in the client. For example, look into the `sendNotification` method from the Firebase Messaging [sample](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/kotlin/MyFirebaseMessagingService.kt):

```kt
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

Here the notification is being generated, and as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68448827/4044241), setting the style in the notification with `setStyle` will result in the behavior your are expecting:

```kt
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.fcm_message))
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(messageBody))
```

This is the result I got:

[image]